# How to convert SPFieldNumber into an int

Tags: c#, sharepoint

How do I convert an `SPFieldNumber` into an `int` in C#?  I tried to use `Convert.ToInt32` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
Convert.ToInt32(MySPFieldNumber.GetFieldValue());
Convert.ToInt32(MySPFieldNumber.GetFieldValueAsText());
```

Comment: The second line was what I had... something else buggered up my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you tried to get a string representation of the SPFieldNumber object and then use Int32.Parse(spfieldnumber_string_value) ?